# Is the closed subscheme theoretic image also the category theoretic image?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

The closed sub schemes theoretic image of a morphism of schemes $\phi : X\rightarrow Y $ is defined to be the scheme theoretic intersection of all closed sub schemes containing $\phi $. In case X is reduced or $\phi $ is quasi compact, the closed sub scheme theoretic image of $\phi $ is just the closed sub scheme of Y cut out by the kernels of $\phi^*(U):\mathscr{O}_Y(U)\rightarrow \mathscr{O}_ X(\phi^{-1}(U)) $ where U is an open affine.

My question is whether this is also the image in the category theoretic sense in the category of schemes. If not which properties of the category theoretic image does it have?

At the very least it seems to be a monomorphism since closed sub schemes are monomorphism

Comment: No. The category theoretic image of an open immersion is just the image (as an open subscheme) and the scheme theoretic image of an open immersion will be its closure.

Comment: I think the category theoretic image would be defined relative to a given factorization system of the category. Probably you could show that there is a (proper) factorization system $(\mathcal E,\mathcal M)$ on the category of schemes (or sufficiently nice ones) which has the closed immersions as $\mathcal M$. Then the $(\mathcal E, \mathcal M)$-image of a map will (equivalently) be the smallest $\mathcal M$-subobject through which it factors, so the scheme-theoretic image.

Comment: The paper  [Categories of Continuous functors, I](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404972900011) by Freyd and Kelly contains an introduction to factorization systems.

Comment: Note also that a factorization system is already uniquely determined by $\mathcal M$ or $\mathcal E$.